# How to create JShell programmatically when SecurityManager is set

Tags: java, jshell

I want to create JShell programmatically when the security manager is set before. However, this causes an access control exception. Without the security manager set the code works correctly. I thought that the Java platform modules have all permissions by default.

What shall I set or configure to create JShell without any exception caused by the security manager?

Below is the code that I tried. I use OpenJDK 12.0.2.

The policy file:

```
grant codeBase "file:${user.dir}/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

The java module:

```
module test {

    requires jdk.jshell;
    requires java.logging;
}
```

The class:

```
package test;

import jdk.jshell.JShell;

public class HelloJShell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URI uri = HelloJShell.class.getResource("/conf/security/java.policy").toURI();
        Policy policy = Policy.getInstance("JavaPolicy", new URIParameter(uri));
        Policy.setPolicy(policy);

        // When the line below is commented the code works fine. 
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        JShell js = JShell.create();
        System.out.println(js);
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URI uri = HelloJShell.class.getResource("/conf/security/java.policy").toURI();
        Policy policy = Policy.getInstance("JavaPolicy", new URIParameter(uri));
        Policy.setPolicy(policy);

        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Void>) () -> {
            try (JShell js = JShell.create()) {
                System.out.println(js);
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

I expect that the JShell will be created without an exception.

It throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Launching JShell execution engine threw: access denied ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control")
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.JShell.<init>(JShell.java:139)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.JShell$Builder.build(JShell.java:405)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.JShell.create(JShell.java:420)
    at test/test.HelloJShell.main(HelloJShell.java:10)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.logging.LoggingPermission" "control")
    at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1044)
    at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:408)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.checkPermission(LogManager.java:2432)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.checkPermission(Logger.java:622)
    at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.setLevel(Logger.java:2001)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.FailOverExecutionControlProvider.logger(FailOverExecutionControlProvider.java:138)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.execution.FailOverExecutionControlProvider.generate(FailOverExecutionControlProvider.java:109)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.spi.ExecutionControl.generate(ExecutionControl.java:179)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.spi.ExecutionControl.generate(ExecutionControl.java:296)
    at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.JShell.<init>(JShell.java:136)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is necessary to configure the following permissions in the policy file:

```
grant codeBase "jrt:/jdk.jshell" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "jrt:/jdk.jdi" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "jrt:/jdk.compiler" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

It is defined here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/security/permissions-jdk1.html#GUID-7450CEFD-8EDC-495E-A7A3-6C2561FA4999

> If you are using a modular runtime image (see the jlink tool), you can
>   grant permissions to the application and library modules in the image
>   by specifying a jrt URL as the codeBase value in a policy file. See
>   JEP 220: Modular Run-Time Images for more information about jrt URLs.