# Java Arithmetic equation string java min(x,y),max(x,y),+,-,/,*

Tags: java, string, math, equation

I want to create a method in Java that receives a string equation,
for example: "3+2"   or   "32-1/3"   or even  "min(32,21)"
and returns the result
I have found ScriptEngine that offers the solution for simple operations :

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
 ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 java.lang.String result;
 result = engine.eval(equation).toString();
```

But it has no min(),max() functionality, and also it's not secure because you can input malicious scripts through.

Comment: Since this is a JavaScript engine, it should have `Math.min` and `Math.max`.

Comment: You can use all java too, define variables and functions. A pure java solution would be **`JShell`**. Like the scripting engine `JShell.create().eval("1+3"):`. Note https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663086/how-to-create-jshell-programmatically-when-securitymanager-is-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great library , I just provide a string math equation and it solves it and offers lots of other functionalities.

It's called mxParser by Mariusz Gromada.

```
import  org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
import  org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.Constant;

  Constant mp = new Constant("mp",0.5);
        String mpString = Double.toString(mp.getConstantValue());
        String equation = "min(max(1,6)," + mpString +")";
        Expression e = new Expression(equation);
        System.out.println(e.calculate());
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment from @kshetline should solve your problem regarding arithmetic expression question; as for security all I can think of would be using some framework for input sanitization, or write up your own implementation.

Check out [How best to sanitize input in Java webapp.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761588/how-best-to-sanitize-input-in-java-webapp)

Hope this helps.